# Web API serialize properties starting from lowercase letter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

How can I configure serialization of my Web API to use `camelCase` (starting from lowercase letter) property names instead of `PascalCase` like it is in C#.

Can I do it globally for the whole project?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you want to change serialization behavior in Newtonsoft.Json aka JSON.NET, you need to create your settings:

```
var jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore // ignore null values
});
```

You can also pass these settings into `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize, serializerSettings);
```

### For ASP.NET MVC and Web API. In Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
      .Formatters
      .JsonFormatter
      .SerializerSettings
      .ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
}
```

Exclude null values:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .Formatters
    .JsonFormatter
    .SerializerSettings
    .NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```

Indicates that null values should not be included in resulting JSON.

### ASP.NET Core

ASP.NET Core by default serializes values in camelCase format.

Comment: mvc6 snippet doesn't work for me on beta6? My `IActionsResult` method returns `Json(listItems)` with PascalCase

Comment: for beta6, you need
 `services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            {
                var formatter = options.OutputFormatters.FirstOrDefault(f => f is JsonOutputFormatter) as JsonOutputFormatter;

                formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                formatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });`

Comment: so what is the solution to change from { MyProp: ''} to { myProp: ''}

Answer (score 7):

For **MVC 6.0.0-rc1-final**

Edit *Startup.cs*, In the `ConfigureServices(IserviceCollection)`, modify `services.AddMvc();`

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var formatter = new JsonOutputFormatter
    {
        SerializerSettings = {ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()}
    };
    options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, formatter);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET CORE 1.0.0 Json serializes have default camelCase.
[Referee this Announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in the newer (vNext) C# 6.0, then you have to configure this through `MvcOptions` in the `ConfigureServices` method located in the `Startup.cs` class file.

```
services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    var jsonOutputFormatter = new JsonOutputFormatter();
    jsonOutputFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    jsonOutputFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;

    options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, jsonOutputFormatter);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out camelCase is the default. But if you don't want this everywhere you can annotate your classes like this.

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class Developer
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("FirstName")]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("LastName")]
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("RowNum")]
    public int RowNum { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("StartDate")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

}
```